# How to fix No value for X in Json

Tags: php, android, json, api

Json Error: No value for sl_summ

php code

```
If($user_sldtl != null) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($user_sldtl); $i++){
       $sl_response["error"] = FALSE;
       $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_brcode"] = $user_sldtl[$i][0];
       $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_memid"] = $user_sldtl[$i][3];
       $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_desc"] = $user_sldtl[$i][7];
       $sl_response["sl_summ"]["tr_date"] = $user_sldtl[$i][10];
       $sl_response["sl_summ"]["actual_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
       $sl_response["sl_summ"]["available_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
       json_encode($sl_response, true);
       echo json_encode($sl_response, true);
              //echo "<br>";
    }

         }
         else {
             // echo "Member's data not found"."<br />";
             // echo "Var dump: ";
             // var_dump($user);
             // echo " ->No record found";
             $sl_response["error"] = TRUE;
             $sl_response["error_msg"] = "NO SL Details found!";
             echo json_encode($sl_response);
         }
```

Json result

first response for the user login.

> {"error":false,"user":{"br_code":12,"mem_id":13,"username":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com","created_at":"2016-07-22 09:05:21"}}

2nd response for the sl_summ. It has two response but dont have the same value for the other columns. the sl_summ response will depend how many rows he had inside the table "sl"

> {"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_brcode":"12","sl_memid":"13","sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account","tr_date":"2015-08-17","actual_balance":"483.67","available_balance":"483.67"}}
>
> {"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_brcode":"12","sl_memid":"13","sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond","tr_date":"2015-08-28","actual_balance":"10129.43","available_balance":"10129.43"}}

***slsumm.java***

```
try {
      JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
      boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

       // Check for error node in json
       if (!error) {
          // user successfully logged in
          // Create login session
          session.setLogin(true);

          // Now store the user in SQLite
          //String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

          JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
          String br_code = user.getString("br_code");
          String mem_id = user.getString("mem_id");
          String username = user.getString("username");
          String email = user.getString("email");
          String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

         // Inserting row in users table
         db.addUser(br_code, mem_id, username, email, created_at);

         JSONObject sl_summ = jObj.getJSONObject("sl_summ");
         String sl_brcode = sl_summ.getString("sl_brcode");
         String sl_memid = sl_summ.getString("sl_memid");
         String sl_desc = sl_summ.getString("sl_desc");
         String tr_date = sl_summ.getString("tr_date");
         String actual_balance = sl_summ.getString("actual_balance");
                    String avail_balance = sl_summ.getString("avail_balance");

       // Inserting row in users table
        db.addUserSLDTL(sl_brcode, sl_memid, sl_desc, tr_date, actual_balance, avail_balance);

       // Launch main activity
       Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
       MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
      } else {
       // Error in login. Get the error message
       String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
      // JSON error
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

SQLiteHandler.java

```
   public void addUserSLDTL(String sl_brcode, String sl_memid, String sl_desc, String tr_date, String  actual_balance, String avail_balance){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SL_BRCODE, sl_brcode); // sl branch code
    values.put(SL_MEMID, sl_memid); // sl mem id
    values.put(SL_DESC, sl_desc); // sl desc
    values.put(TR_DATE, tr_date); // trans date
    values.put(ACTUAL_BALANCE, actual_balance); // actual balance
    values.put(AVAILABLE_BALANCE, avail_balance); // availabe balance

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "User SL Details inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}

   public HashMap<String, String> getUserSLDTL() {
    HashMap<String, String> sl_summ = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        sl_summ.put("sl_brcode", cursor.getString(0));
        sl_summ.put("sl_memid", cursor.getString(1));
        sl_summ.put("sl_desc", cursor.getString(2));
        sl_summ.put("tr_date", cursor.getString(3));
        sl_summ.put("actual_balance", cursor.getString(4));
        sl_summ.put("avail_balance", cursor.getString(5));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + sl_summ.toString());

    return sl_summ;
}
```

Comment: sorry didn't understood your problem could you please elaborate more??

Comment: When I login, it will retrun an Json Error: no value for sl_summ. even though  it has a value in sl_summ.

Comment: can you share code how are you getting json during login??

Comment: can you print your complete response that you're getting and share it because the response you shared is incomplete??

Comment: Before I can login successfully, but when I added the code from JSONObject sl_summ = jObj.getJSONObject("sl_summ"); to db.addUserSLDTL(sl_brcode, sl_memid, sl_desc, tr_date, actual_balance, avail_balance);
and soon. The Error appeared.

Comment: ok wait checking

Comment: one last question is this one complete JSON response or 3 different responses. If it's one response then your JSON response is wrong you won't be able to parse it.

Comment: 2 different response sir. 1 for the user from br_code to created_at column for the login and the the sl_summ for the summary. the sl_summ result will depend how many rows  he had inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have parsed user data.

For sl_summ use this:

I have taken your response in a String you can directly do it from your response:

```
private static String sl_summResponse = "{\n" +
            "  \"error\": false,\n" +
            "  \"sl_summ\": {\n" +
            "    \"sl_brcode\": \"12\",\n" +
            "    \"sl_memid\": \"13\",\n" +
            "    \"sl_desc\": \"PA : Savings Account\",\n" +
            "    \"tr_date\": \"2015-08-17\",\n" +
            "    \"actual_balance\": \"483.67\",\n" +
            "    \"available_balance\": \"483.67\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "  \"error\": false,\n" +
            "  \"sl_summ\": {\n" +
            "    \"sl_brcode\": \"12\",\n" +
            "    \"sl_memid\": \"13\",\n" +
            "    \"sl_desc\": \"PA : Savings - Cash Bond\",\n" +
            "    \"tr_date\": \"2015-08-28\",\n" +
            "    \"actual_balance\": \"10129.43\",\n" +
            "    \"available_balance\": \"10129.43\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
```

then parse your response like this:

```
try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sl_summResponse);
            Boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
            Log.e("Test","Error : "+error);
            if (!error){
                JSONArray sl_summ = jObj.optJSONArray("sl_summ");
                for (int i =0;i<sl_summ.length();i++){
                    JSONObject rootObj = sl_summ.getJSONObject(i);
                    String sl_brcode = rootObj.getString("sl_brcode");
                    String sl_memid = rootObj.getString("sl_memid");
                    String sl_desc = rootObj.getString("sl_desc");
                    String tr_date = rootObj.getString("tr_date");
                    String actual_balance = rootObj.getString("actual_balance");
                    String avail_balance = rootObj.getString("avail_balance");
                    // then do whatever you want with this data
                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUserSLDTL(sl_brcode, sl_memid, sl_desc, tr_date, actual_balance, avail_balance);
                }
            }
```

Comment: but sir I dont know the exact value for the private static String sl_summResponse. because the data is dynamic it will depends what will be the data inside the table "SL""

Comment: some user has 1 data inside SL table some has 2 or more... how can I make it dynamic sir?

Comment: Np whatever the value is I have taken the array whether it has one value or 20 won't make a difference. It is already dyanmic

Comment: sir can you explain it to me how the private static String sl_summResponse works?

Comment: See in your sl_summ response you'll get an array I have just parsed that array similar to how you have parsed the user object. If you want to understand more google how to parse a JSON array.

Comment: ah ok sir.. Im just curious if it is needed to follow private static String sl_summResponse formatting above..

Comment: thnx for your response. im just new to this thing. :)

Comment: No no you don't have to do that since you'll be getting response from the server like this String use that I have used this String because I am not getting any response from the server. Change this line in your code:
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseFromtheServer);

Comment: okie2x sir.. thnx... il try it on my code. If it solved the error ill accept it.

Comment: sir @sumit after adding the code above the  error jsason has no value is gone. but sad to say there is another error. after Iog in the app will automatically close and cannot be re open again. I will open another question and will give the link in comment. hope you will guide me how to solve those error.

Comment: this the link sir. hope you will help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690081/shutting-down-android-app-after-i-login

Comment: good day @sumit. Sir after I fix the error in the first link that I give you, the error json has no value appear again.. but I can login the app will not stop. here is the link sir. hope you can help me solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666854/how-to-fix-no-value-for-x-in-json

Comment: share your new code and paste the exact error from logcat and start a fresh question I am not able to understand your error from this.

Comment: this is the link of my new question sir@sumit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694315/json-error-value-sl-summ-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-json-o/44694919?noredirect=1#comment76373590_44694919