# Json Error: Value sl_summ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSON OBJECT

Tags: php, android, json, api

How to fix this error. Hope you can guide me how to solve this problem I encountered my just new to android programming. I only followed the code in a tutorail and make some changes to it.

After I login it will Toast a message Json Error: Value sl_summ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONOBJECT 
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2l20.png) of the toast error after logging in

**login.php**

```
$user_sldtl = $db->getUserSLsummary($arclass, $loanclass, $accintreceivable, 
$date, $year, $month, $br_code, $clientid);

        If($user_sldtl != null) {
             for($i = 0; $i < count($user_sldtl); $i++){
              $sl_response["error"] = FALSE;
            //   $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_brcode"] = $user_sldtl[$i][0];
            //   $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_memid"] = $user_sldtl[$i][3];
              $sl_response["sl_summ"]["sl_desc"] = $user_sldtl[$i][7];
              $sl_response["sl_summ"]["tr_date"] = $user_sldtl[$i][10];
              $sl_response["sl_summ"]["actual_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
              $sl_response["sl_summ"]["available_balance"] = $user_sldtl[$i][14];
              json_encode($sl_response, true);
              echo json_encode($sl_response, true);
              //echo "<br>";
           }

         }
         else {
             // echo "Member's data not found"."<br />";
             // echo "Var dump: ";
             // var_dump($user);
             // echo " ->No record found";
             $sl_response["error"] = TRUE;
             $sl_response["error_msg"] = "NO SL Details found!";
             echo json_encode($sl_response);
         }
```

**JSON Response**

this response is from members table.

```
{
 "error":false,
    "user":
        {
            "br_code":12,
            "mem_id":13,
            "username":"test",
            "email":"test@yahoo.com"
            ,"created_at":"2016-07-22 09:05:21"
        }
}
```

this response is from sl_summ this user has 2 rows in the table

```
{
    "error": false,
    "sl_summ": 
        [
            {
                "sl_desc": "PA : Savings Account",
                "tr_date": "2015-08-17",
                "actual_balance": "483.67",
                "available_balance": "483.67"
            }, 
            {
                "sl_desc": "PA : Savings - Cash Bond",
                "tr_date": "2015-08-28",
                "actual_balance": "10129.43",
                "available_balance": "10129.43"
            }
        ]
}
```

SQLiteHandler.java

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "coredev_gsacwp";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_MEMBERS = "members";
private static final String TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL = "sldtl";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String BR_CODE = "br_code";
private static final String MEM_ID = "mem_id";
private static final String MEM_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String MEM_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String MEM_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

// Members SL Details
private static final String SL_DESC = "sl_desc";
private static final String TR_DATE = "trans_date";
private static final String ACTUAL_BALANCE = "actual_balance";
private static final String AVAILABLE_BALANCE = "available_balance";

public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBERS + "("
            + BR_CODE + " INTEGER,"
            + MEM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + MEM_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + MEM_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + MEM_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    //Members SLDTL table
    String CREATE_SLDTL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL + "("
            + SL_DESC + " TEXT,"
            + TR_DATE + " DATETIME,"
            + ACTUAL_BALANCE + " REAL,"
            + AVAILABLE_BALANCE + " REAL" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SLDTL_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database table created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBERS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String br_code, String mem_id, String username, String email, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BR_CODE, br_code); // branch code
    values.put(MEM_ID, mem_id); // mem id
    values.put(MEM_USERNAME, username); // username
    values.put(MEM_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(MEM_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBERS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}
/**
 * Storing user SL details in database
 * */
public void addUserSLDTL(String sl_desc, String tr_date, String  actual_balance, String avail_balance){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SL_DESC, sl_desc); // sl desc
    values.put(TR_DATE, tr_date); // trans date
    values.put(ACTUAL_BALANCE, actual_balance); // actual balance
    values.put(AVAILABLE_BALANCE, avail_balance); // availabe balance

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "User SL Details inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}
/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("br_code", cursor.getString(0));
        user.put("mem_id", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}
/**
 * Getting user SL details data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserSLDTL() {
    HashMap<String, String> sl_summ = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        sl_summ.put("sl_desc", cursor.getString(0));
        sl_summ.put("tr_date", cursor.getString(1));
        sl_summ.put("actual_balance", cursor.getString(2));
        sl_summ.put("avail_balance", cursor.getString(3));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + sl_summ.toString());

    return sl_summ;
}

/**
 * Re create database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_MEMBERS, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "All user info are now deleted in sqlite");
}
/**
 * Re create database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUserSLDTL() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_MEMBERS_SLDTL, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "All user's SLDTL info are now deleted in sqlite");
}
```

}

**Login.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputUsername;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(username, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://gsac.ph/iaccswebportal/register.php");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in

                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    //String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String br_code = user.getString("br_code");
                    String mem_id = user.getString("mem_id");
                    String username = user.getString("username");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(br_code, mem_id, username, email, created_at);
                    try {
                        JSONObject sl_jObj  = new JSONObject("sl_summ");
                        Boolean sl_error = sl_jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        Log.e("Test", "Error : " + sl_error);
                        if (!sl_error) {
                            JSONArray sl_summ = sl_jObj.optJSONArray("sl_summ");
                            for (int i = 0; i < sl_summ.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject rootObj = sl_summ.getJSONObject(i);
                                String sl_desc = rootObj.getString("sl_desc");
                                String tr_date = rootObj.getString("tr_date");
                                String actual_balance = rootObj.getString("actual_balance");
                                String avail_balance = rootObj.getString("avail_balance");
                                // then do whatever you want with this data
                                // Inserting row in users table
                                db.addUserSLDTL(sl_desc, tr_date, actual_balance, avail_balance);
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

**Message log**

```
Login Response: {"error":false,"user":{"br_code":12,"mem_id":13,"username":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com","created_at":"2016-07-22 09:05:21"}}<br /><br />{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account","tr_date":"2015-08-17","actual_balance":"483.67","available_balance":"483.67"}}{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond","tr_date":"2015-08-28","actual_balance":"10129.43","available_balance":"10129.43"}}
    06-22 16:07:30.456 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@48e3e97[LoginActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
    06-22 16:07:30.470 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=85
    06-22 16:07:30.478 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/SessionManager: User login session modified!
    06-22 16:07:30.498 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/SQLiteHandler: New user inserted into sqlite: 13
    06-22 16:07:30.499 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value sl_summ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    06-22 16:07:30.500 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    06-22 16:07:30.500 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:147)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:116)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-22 16:07:30.501 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    06-22 16:07:30.502 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    06-22 16:07:30.502 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    06-22 16:07:30.502 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    06-22 16:07:30.502 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
    06-22 16:07:30.560 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@7c78859[LoginActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    06-22 16:07:30.564 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
    06-22 16:07:30.579 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=81
    06-22 16:07:30.579 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@6834e69[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{60290ee V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
    06-22 16:07:30.604 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@7c78859[LoginActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
    06-22 16:07:30.623 24346-24418/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [907x245]-format:1
    06-22 16:07:30.692 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=gsac_tabaco@yahoo.com, created_at=2016-07-22 09:05:21, br_code=12, mem_id=13, username=novalyn}
    06-22 16:07:30.696 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {}
    06-22 16:07:30.708 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=85
    06-22 16:07:30.708 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@bc7f138[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@8f0f511[MainActivity] touchMode=true
    06-22 16:07:30.709 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@6834e69[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-22 16:07:30.746 24346-24418/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
    06-22 16:07:30.811 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@bc7f138[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
    06-22 16:07:30.811 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@bc7f138[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    06-22 16:07:30.813 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@38d1e4e nm : ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal ic=null
    06-22 16:07:30.814 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
    06-22 16:07:30.825 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=98
    06-22 16:07:30.825 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=79
    06-22 16:07:30.839 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
    06-22 16:07:31.258 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@7c78859[LoginActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
    06-22 16:07:31.272 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=84
    06-22 16:07:34.027 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@6834e69[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
    06-22 16:07:34.037 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=81
    06-22 16:08:04.047 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@a5db6f nm : ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal ic=null
    06-22 16:08:04.048 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
    06-22 16:08:04.055 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=80
    06-22 16:08:04.056 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=98
    06-22 16:08:09.686 24346-24346/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/ViewRootImpl@bc7f138[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
```

Comment: please paste your jSONResponse as such, its not easy to make out anything from your jsonresponse.

Comment: sorry sir but I dont know how to have a readable json response. I only copy and paste it in the browser. can you tell me sir how to have a more readable json response? Like in some tutorials.. I will just edit my json response sir.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your message log, is that you're trying to convert this :

```
Login Response: {"error":false,"user":{"br_code":12,"mem_id":13,"username":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com","created_at":"2016-07-22 09:05:21"}}<br /><br />{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account","tr_date":"2015-08-17","actual_balance":"483.67","available_balance":"483.67"}}{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond","tr_date":"2015-08-28","actual_balance":"10129.43","available_balance":"10129.43"}}
```

into a JSONObject.

And I see at least 2 errors in this :

- There is some HTML element : `<br /><br />` that you need to remove first.
- There is multiple JSON file

So, after removing the HTML elements, you will need to either :

- Parse that Login Response, and make multiple JSON Object;
- Or create a JSON Array out of your Login Response.

You can use this [website](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Comment: sir the the HTML elements is already removed. can you so me a sample code in how to parse that login response and make multiple JSON Object or create a JSON array out of my Login Response?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your `<br />` tag in response.

You are having your response as

```
Login Response: {"error":false,"user":{"br_code":12,"mem_id":13,"username":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com","created_at":"2016-07-22 09:05:21"}}<br /><br />{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account","tr_date":"2015-08-17","actual_balance":"483.67","available_balance":"483.67"}}{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond","tr_date":"2015-08-28","actual_balance":"10129.43","available_balance":"10129.43"}}
```

these `<br>` tags are because of you php code.

Also your `sl_summ` is not an jsonArray. Its a Json object.

```
{
 "error":false,
 "sl_summ":
        {
            "sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account",
            "tr_date":"2015-08-17",
            "actual_balance":"483.67",
            "available_balance":"483.67"
        }
}

{
 "error":false,
 "sl_summ":
        {
            "sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond",
            "tr_date":"2015-08-28",
            "actual_balance":"10129.43",
            "available_balance":"10129.43"
        }
}
```

so when you are writing `JSONArray sl_summ = sl_jObj.optJSONArray("sl_summ");` This JsonObject is not converted to JsonArray that in turn giving you error.

You should correct your json as,

```
{
 "error":false,
 "sl_summ":
        [{
            "sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account",
            "tr_date":"2015-08-17",
            "actual_balance":"483.67",
            "available_balance":"483.67"
        },
        {
            "sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond",
            "tr_date":"2015-08-28",
            "actual_balance":"10129.43",
            "available_balance":"10129.43"
        }]
}
```

Comment: sir  the <br /> <br /> was already remove but the problem still persist.

Comment: how to convert json Object to json Array sir? my json response is from my php api sir.

Comment: I already converted my Json Object to json array sir by using this code **$arr = array(
                               'sl_desc' =>  $user_sldtl[$i][7],
                               'tr_date' => $user_sldtl[$i][10],
                               'actual_balance' => $user_sldtl[$i][14],
                               'available_balance' => $user_sldtl[$i][14]
                              );
                  echo json_encode($arr, true);**

Answer (score 0):

Change your jsonobect for sl_summ like this

```
   JsonObject  json =  new JsonObject(response);
          if(json.has("sl_summ"){

         JSONObject sl_jObj  = new JSONObject(json.getString("sl_summ"));
}
```

Comment: sir after I change to code the error was change to  no value for sl_summ **06-22 17:14:56.776 25354-25354/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal D/SQLiteHandler: New user inserted into sqlite: 13
06-22 17:14:56.777 25354-25354/ph.coredev.johnjessbayutas.gsacmobileportal W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for sl_summ**

Comment: The Toast message was gone after I updated the code.. but the problem is after Logging in and I check the Log cat no value was fetch.  **Fetching user from Sqlite sl_summ table: {}**

Comment: Here is the Login response **Login Response: {"error":false,"user":{"br_code":12,"mem_id":13,"username":"novalyn","email":"gsac_tabaco@yahoo.com","created_at":"2016-07-22 09:05:21"}}{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings Account","tr_date":"2015-08-17","actual_balance":"483.67","available_balance":"483.67"}}{"error":false,"sl_summ":{"sl_desc":"PA : Savings - Cash Bond","tr_date":"2015-08-28","actual_balance":"10129.43","available_balance":"10129.43"}}** by the way thank you for helping me..

Comment: @John something is there in your json make it correct?

Comment: pardon me sir @Sandeep dhiman. is there something wrong with may json response sir? that's why it was not inserted in the sldtl table?

Comment: @ Sandeep dhiman  sir I already fix my json format. hope you can help me sir.

Comment: yes sir. I will edit my question with my current json response